# Macbook Pro Rentina 2015 suddenly restart without giving any message

Tags: macbook-pro, kernel-panic, restart

My Macbook just suddenly restarted last night. I did some research on this morning and I found my log of kernel panic as below. Please may you help me to find what was the cause and how to solve it?

```
Anonymous UUID:       0CBB079C-6D4F-05EE-412B-C26A278F2D4B



Sat Jul  7 23:23:25 2018



*** MCA Error Report ***

CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5287U CPU @ 2.90GHz, CPUID: 0x306D4)

Core: 0

  IA32_MC4_STATUS=0xBE00000000800400

  IA32_MC4_CTL=0x0

  IA32_MC4_ADDR=0xFFFFFF8008834B42

  IA32_MC4_MISC=0xFFFFFF8008834B42

Core: 0

  IA32_MC5_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110B

  IA32_MC5_CTL=0x0

  IA32_MC5_ADDR=0xFF7075C0

  IA32_MC5_MISC=0x3880000086

Core: 0

  IA32_MC6_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110B

  IA32_MC6_CTL=0x0

  IA32_MC6_ADDR=0xFF70FBC0

  IA32_MC6_MISC=0x3880000086





*** Device Tree ***

{

    "pcie_cfg_base" : "0xe0000000",

    "pci_devices" :

    {

        "0x0" : "MCHC@0",

        "0x10000" : "IGPU@2",

        "0x18000" : "HDAU@3",

        "0xa0000" : "XHC1@14",

        "0xac000" : "SPI1@15,4",

        "0xa8000" : "SDMA@15",

        "0xb0000" : "pci8086,9cba@16",

        "0xd8000" : "HDEF@1B",

        "0xe0000" : "RP01@1C",

        "0xe2000" : "RP03@1C,2",

        "0xe1000" : "RP02@1C,1",

        "0xe4000" : "RP05@1C,4",

        "0x200000" : "RP02@1C,1/IOPP/CMRA@0",

        "0x300000" : "RP03@1C,2/IOPP/ARPT@0",

        "0x500000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0",

        "0x600000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0",

        "0x618000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB1@3",

        "0x620000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB2@4",

        "0x628000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB3@5",

        "0x700000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0",

        "0x630000" : "RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB4@6",

        "0xf8000" : "LPCB@1F",

        "0xfb000" : "SBUS@1F,3",

        "0xfe000" : "pci8086,9ca4@1F,6",

        "0xe5000" : "RP06@1C,5",

        "0x400000" : "RP06@1C,5/IOPP/SSD0@0"

    },

    "device_mmio" :

    {

        "PCI0@0" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xcf8", "s" : "0x8" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/IGPU@2" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa0000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },

            { "a" : "0x7f90000000", "s" : "0x10000000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/HDAU@3" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa1014000", "s" : "0x4000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/XHC1@14" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa1000000", "s" : "0x10000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SDMA@15" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xc181a000", "s" : "0x1000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SPI1@15,4" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xc1819000", "s" : "0x1000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/pci8086,9cba@16" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa1019100", "s" : "0x20" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/HDEF@1B" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa1010000", "s" : "0x4000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP02@1C,1/IOPP/CMRA@0" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xc1700000", "s" : "0x10000" },

            { "a" : "0x7f80000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },

            { "a" : "0xc1600000", "s" : "0x100000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP03@1C,2/IOPP/ARPT@0" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xc1400000", "s" : "0x8000" },

            { "a" : "0xc1000000", "s" : "0x400000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP05@1C,4/IOPP/UPSB@0/IOPP/DSB0@0/IOPP/NHI0@0" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xc1900000", "s" : "0x40000" },

            { "a" : "0xc1940000", "s" : "0x1000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/RP06@1C,5/IOPP/SSD0@0" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xc1500000", "s" : "0x2000" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SBUS@1F,3" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa1019000", "s" : "0x100" }

        ],

        "PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/pci8086,9ca4@1F,6" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x7fa1018000", "s" : "0x1000" }

        ],

        "DMAC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x0", "s" : "0x20" },

            { "a" : "0x81", "s" : "0x11" },

            { "a" : "0x93", "s" : "0xd" },

            { "a" : "0xc0", "s" : "0x20" }

        ],

        "FWHD" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" }

        ],

        "HPET" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xfed00000", "s" : "0x4000" }

        ],

        "IPIC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x20", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x24", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x28", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x2c", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x30", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x34", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x38", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x3c", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xa0", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xa4", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xa8", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xac", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xb0", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xb4", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xb8", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xbc", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x4d0", "s" : "0x2" }

        ],

        "MATH" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xf0", "s" : "0x1" }

        ],

        "LDRC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x2e", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x4e", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0x61", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x63", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x65", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x67", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x80", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x92", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0xb2", "s" : "0x2" },

            { "a" : "0xffff", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x1800", "s" : "0x80" },

            { "a" : "0x800", "s" : "0x80" }

        ],

        "RTC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x70", "s" : "0x8" }

        ],

        "TIMR" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x40", "s" : "0x4" },

            { "a" : "0x50", "s" : "0x4" }

        ],

        "SMC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x300", "s" : "0x20" },

            { "a" : "0xfef00000", "s" : "0x10000" }

        ],

        "EC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x62", "s" : "0x1" },

            { "a" : "0x66", "s" : "0x1" }

        ],

        "PDRC" :

        [

            { "a" : "0xfed1c000", "s" : "0x4000" },

            { "a" : "0xfed10000", "s" : "0x8000" },

            { "a" : "0xfed18000", "s" : "0x1000" },

            { "a" : "0xfed19000", "s" : "0x1000" },

            { "a" : "0xe0000000", "s" : "0x10000000" },

            { "a" : "0xfed20000", "s" : "0x20000" },

            { "a" : "0xfed90000", "s" : "0x4000" },

            { "a" : "0xfed45000", "s" : "0x4b000" },

            { "a" : "0xff000000", "s" : "0x1000000" },

            { "a" : "0xfee00000", "s" : "0x100000" }

        ],

        "MEM2" :

        [

            { "a" : "0x20000000", "s" : "0x200000" },

            { "a" : "0x40000000", "s" : "0x200000" }

        ]

    }

}
```

Comment: Start with [AHT - Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).  Hold D while booting from a powered off state with the AC adapter attached.

Comment: @Allan, it said: No problems are found :(